# Changes made in web template do not show on frontend?

Tags: magento2, template, template-override

I am using **Magento 2.2.3** and I am modifying a template from a custom extension. That path to the template is `app/code/Foo/Osc/view/frontend/web/template/container/address/billing/create.html`

I am just adding another class or some plain HTML, but after recompiling, redeploying and cleaning caches, the changes are not reflecting on the frontend. I even deleted `var/view_preprocessed`.

Is there something else that has to be done?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this file is being used to overwrite that block with your new block because if its not being output then it is most likley that the standard checkout block is being used

Comment: Yes I am, I greped for the content and its only one file that uses it.

Comment: Do you map the templates using requirejs-config.js?

Comment: is the module enabled? maybe your theme overwrites the file from you module

Comment: Do you have cache enabled on the website? if so disable it and recheck i have been having a few issues with the cache on M2.2 recently